# Can I have an optional OUTPUT parameter in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, data-access

I have a stored procedure that has a bunch of input and output parameters because it is Inserting values to multiple tables.  In some cases the stored proc only inserts to a single table (depending on the input parameters).  Here is a mocked up scenario to illustrate.

Tables / Data Objects:

**Person**

```
Id
Name
Address
```

**Name**

```
Id
FirstName
LastName
```

**Address**

```
Id
Country
City
```

Say I have a stored procedure that inserts a person. If the address doesn't exist I won't add it to the `Address` table in the database.

Thus when I generate the code to call the stored procedure I don't want to bother adding the `Address` parameter. For `INPUT` parameters this is ok because SQL Server allows me to supply default values. But for the `OUTPUT` parameter what do I do in the stored procedure to make it optional so I do not receive an error...

> *Procedure or function 'Person_InsertPerson' expects parameter
>   '@AddressId', which was not supplied.*

Comment: What does your code look like? That is, somewhere you're branching on whether an address exists. I'm suspicious my question, once seeing that branch, would be, "Why not call the sproc with `NULL` in whatever you pass for `@AddressId` when an address doesn't exist, *without* using a branch?"

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Both input and output parameters can be assigned defaults. In this example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTest
  @Data1 int
 ,@Data2 int = 0
 ,@Data3 int = null output

AS

PRINT @Data1
PRINT @Data2
PRINT isnull(@Data3, -1)

SET @Data3 = @Data3 + 1

RETURN 0
```

the first paramter is required, and the second and third are optional--if not set by the calling routine, they will be assigned the default values. Try messing around with it and the following test-call routine in SSMS using different values and settings to see how it all works together.

```
DECLARE @Output int

SET @Output = 3

EXECUTE MyTest
  @Data1 = 1
 ,@Data2 = 2
 ,@Data3 = @Output output

PRINT '---------'
PRINT @Output
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why I couldn't use `@var INT OUTPUT = NULL` -- the syntax is confusing.

Comment: doesn't really invoke the default value (you set @output) defaults only activate when you DON'T pass something, see my answer for complete treatment.

Answer (score 17):

Output parameters and default values do not work well together!  This is from SQL 10.50.1617 (2008 R2).  *Do not be fooled* into believing this construct magically does a `SET` to that value on your behalf (like my co-worker did)!

This "toy" SP interrogates the `OUTPUT` parameter value, whether it is the default value or `NULL`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[omgwtf] (@Qty INT, @QtyRetrieved INT = 0 OUTPUT)
AS
IF @QtyRetrieved = 0
BEGIN
    print 'yay its zero'
END
IF @QtyRetrieved is null
BEGIN
    print 'wtf its NULL'
END
RETURN
```

If you send in an uninitialized value (i.e. `NULL`) for the `OUTPUT`, you really got `NULL` inside the SP, and not `0`.  Makes sense, something got passed for that parameter.

```
declare @QR int
exec [dbo].[omgwtf] 1, @QR output
print '@QR=' + coalesce(convert(varchar, @QR),'NULL')
```

output is:

```
wtf its NULL
@QR=NULL
```

If we add an explicit `SET` from the caller we get:

```
declare @QR int
set @QR = 999
exec [dbo].[omgwtf] 1, @QR output
print '@QR=' + coalesce(convert(varchar, @QR),'NULL')
```

and the (unsurprising) output:

```
@QR=999
```

Again, makes sense, a parameter is passed, and SP took no explicit action to `SET` a value.

Add a `SET` of the `OUTPUT` parameter in the SP (like you're supposed to do), but do not set anything from the caller:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[omgwtf] (@Qty INT, @QtyRetrieved INT = 0 OUTPUT)
AS
IF @QtyRetrieved = 0
BEGIN
    print 'yay its zero'
END
IF @QtyRetrieved is null
BEGIN
    print 'wtf its NULL'
END
SET @QtyRetrieved = @Qty
RETURN
```

Now when executed:

```
declare @QR int
exec [dbo].[omgwtf] 1234, @QR output
print '@QR=' + coalesce(convert(varchar, @QR),'NULL')
```

the output is:

```
wtf its NULL
@QR=1234
```

This is the "standard" behavior for `OUTPUT` parameter handling in SPs.

Now for the **plot twist**: The only way to get the default value to "activate", is to **not pass the `OUTPUT` parameter at all**, which IMHO makes little sense: since it's set up as an `OUTPUT` parameter, that would mean returning something "important" that should be collected.

```
declare @QR int
exec [dbo].[omgwtf] 1
print '@QR=' + coalesce(convert(varchar, @QR),'NULL')
```

gives this output:

```
yay its zero
@QR=NULL
```

But this fails to capture the SPs output, presumably the purpose of that SP to begin with.

IMHO this feature combination is a dubious construct I would consider a *code smell* (phew!!)

Comment: What's the advantage, over terseness (including reusing variables in code that might call this and other sprocs), to using `OUTPUT` parameters for input? Why not pass those input values in as "regular" parameters?

Comment: @ruffin there's no advantage; optional OUTPUT parameters do not work as everyone expects, which is why i built this answer.

Comment: +1. I think I'd just add that that means passing in values via `OUTPUT` params c/sh/ould be considered a bad idea for two reasons: 1. Ideological/code smell, and 2. Practical reasons from the behavior you've found here. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So, moral of the story, if you're going to use optional OUTPUT parameters, always set the default value to NULL (and hold your nose from the smell).

Comment: Actually moral is DO NOT use those two "features" together...nose-holding is optional ;-)

Comment: Um, by the way, this is also true of optional input parameters.  It isn't anything special about output parameters.  If you explicitly pass the parameter with a NULL value, that value will not be overridden by the default value of the parameter.  I don't see why this is some unexpected pitfall, it is the documented, expected behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I can just add a default value to the `OUTPUT` parameter such as:

```
@AddressId int = -1 Output
```

Seems like its poor in terms of readability since `AddressId` is intended strictly as an `OUTPUT` variable.  But it works.  Please let me know if you have a better solution.

Comment: this has pitfalls, see my answer for complete treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are executing a stored procedure and not a SQL statement, you have to set the command type of your SQL Command to Stored Procedure:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Taken from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10146343/procedure-or-function-.aspx).

Also, once you get that error removed, you can use SQL's `nvl()` function in your procedure to specify what you want displayed when a NULL value is encountered.

Sorry about not properly addressing the question...must have misunderstood you. Here's an example of nvl, which I think might address it a little better?

```
select NVL(supplier_city, 'n/a')
from suppliers;
```

The SQL statement above would return 'n/a' if the `supplier_city` field contained a null value. Otherwise, it would return the `supplier_city` value.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

I'm using the Enterprise Library's db.GetStoredProcCommand which will do that for me.  I have called many stored procs in this way and they work quite well.

eg. Code to call the StoredProc
using (DbCommand insertPersonCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Person_InsertPerson"))
            {
                this.AppendInsertPersonParameters(db, insertPersonCommand);
                db.ExecuteNonQuery(insertPersonCommand, dbTransaction);

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what Philip said:

I had a stored procedure in my sql server database that looked like the following:

```
dbo.<storedProcedure>
(@current_user char(8) = NULL,
@current_phase char(3) OUTPUT)
```

And I was calling it from my .net code as the following:

```
 DataTable dt = SqlClient.ExecuteDataTable(<connectionString>, <storedProcedure>);
```

I was getting an System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function  expects parameter '@current_phase', which was not supplied.

I am also using this function somewhere else in my program and passing in a parameter and handling the output one.  So that I didn't have to modify the current call I was making I just changed the stored procedure to make the output parameter also optional.

So it now looks as the following:

```
dbo.<storedProcedure>
(@current_user char(8) = NULL,
@current_phase char(3) = NULL OUTPUT)
```