# Stored procedure's output parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In SQL Server, is an `OUTPUT` parameter actually an `INPUT/OUTPUT` parameter? I'm assuming this since even if we specify the `OUTPUT` keyword for a parameter in the stored procedure definition, we are still required to supply value for this parameter when calling a stored procedure.

Comment: yes, it is in-out, but you can easily test it out on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to provide a value for the output parameter.

For example, of you create a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROC sales_for_type @type VARCHAR(55), @total_sales INT OUTPUT
AS
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM sales a, titles b
WHERE
a.title_id = b.title_id
and
b.type = @type
```

and then you call it like:

```
DECLARE @total_sales_business int
EXEC sales_for_type business, @total_sales=@total_sales_business OUTPUT
```

Check [this article](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_&_Return_Values).

Comment: I assume when we call sales_for_type via "EXEC sales_for_type business, @total_sales=@total_sales_business OUTPUT", the value passed to @total_sales is Null?! Anyways, thank you both for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an output parameter is also an input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is both **input and output** as others already answered. But in case you don't want to be forced to give an input parameter, you can easily **set a default value** in the parameter declaration.
See also this question: [Can I have an optional OUTPUT parameter in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3267523/34022)