# Why is the default value in the output parameter of this stored procedure not returning?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Here is the following procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spM2016_ErrorNumberDesignator 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@procid     int = 0, 
@debug      int = 0,
@errorNum   int = 60000 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql            nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @params         nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @error1List     nvarchar(max) = '''spM2016_FullTableName'', ''spM2016_NullCheckQuoteName_SchemaDBTable_Names''' 
DECLARE @procResults    TABLE ([name] sysname);

--SET @errorNum = 60000; uncomment this line

SET @sql = N'SELECT name ' +
           N'FROM sys.objects ' +
           N'WHERE OBJECT_NAME(@proc) IS NOT NULL ' +
           N'AND ' +
           N'name = OBJECT_NAME(@proc) ' +
           N'AND ' +
           N'OBJECT_NAME(@proc) IN (@error1List); ';
SET @params = N'@proc   int';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@error1List', @error1List);

IF (@debug = 1)
    PRINT REPLACE(@sql, '@proc', @procid);
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @procResults EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params, @proc = @procid;

    IF (@debug = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM @procResults;
        SET @errorNum = 60000;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @procResults)
        BEGIN
            SET @errorNum = 60001;
        END
    END
END
END
GO
```

Can anyone explain to me why the @errorNum parameter output its default value of 60000 when the line `SET @errorNum = 60000` is uncommented, but doesn't output 60000 when the line is commented?

For example, when I execute the procedure with `@procid = 0` and try and print the `@errorNum` I get what seems to be an empty value. Does it have something to do with how I've written my if statements?

Here's the code I'm using for execution:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @procid int
DECLARE @debug int
DECLARE @errorNum int

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

SET @debug = 0;
SET @procid = 0;

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[spM2016_ErrorNumberDesignator] 
   @procid
  ,@debug
  ,@errorNum OUTPUT

PRINT @errorNum;
GO
```

Comment: I don't think that it's even supposed to work that way. Default value is for the parameter when you call the procedure without that parameter.

Comment: Look at this, specifcally escape-llc's answer. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267523/can-i-have-an-optional-output-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Confusing. Thanks Jon.