# Stored procedure default value output parameter is ignored?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have this simple procedure where I don't quite understand the behavior.

I want my procedure to return a default value if no other value is assigned to it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
    @TestVariable int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @TestVariable
END
```

In my opinion this code should return `0`. Since I put the default value to `0`, but it returns `NULL`.

What is the point of this default value since it doesn't seem to affect the variable in any way?

The only solution I've found is to change it to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
    @TestVariable int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @TestVariable IS NULL 
        SET @TestVariable = 0

    SELECT @TestVariable
END
```

If that's the only way then fine, but what's the point of the default value inside the parameter block? If I create a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test2]
    @number1 int = 5,
    @number2 int = 5
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @number1 + @number2
END
```

And don't pass in any variables the default values will be used and the returned result will be `10`. If I change the `@number1` And `@number2` to `OUTPUT` parameters the answer will default to `NULL` again. I hope someone can clear up this confusing behavior for me.

I tried the same with normal parameters that aren't passed back after the procedure and those seem to work fine.

Also, I know I don't have to `SELECT` the output variable since it is returned automatically when I call the procedure, but it was just for testing purposes.

Execute statement:

```
DECLARE @Test int

EXEC [dbo].[Test] @TestVariable = @Test OUTPUT

SELECT @Test
```

**ANSWER: Credit to @Panagiotis Kanavos**

When trying to map the OUTPUT parameter to a variable it will take the variable and also take it as INPUT paramater like a normal variable. I wasn't aware of this double behaviour.

The default only works when no variable is mapped to the OUTPUT parameter and it's still used inside the stored procedure.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3267652/14434828) helped me understand the behaivour.

Comment: Show us your `EXEC` statements - or are you calling this from `SqlCommand` (with `CommandType.StoredProcedure`?) - or something else like an ORM?

Comment: @Dai I added the execute statement.

Comment: A simple reproduction of your issue: `DECLARE @t int = 1; EXEC [dbo].[Test]; EXEC [dbo].[Test] @t`. Just analyze the results.

Comment: @Zhorov `EXEC [dbo].[Test]` returns 0 and `EXEC [dbo].[Test] @t` returns 1

Comment: The variable you use in your execute code has a value, NULL, so the default isn't used. The parameter isn't missing

Comment: Perhaps the real question is why `OUTPUT` parameter acts as an INPUT/OUTPUT parameter? That's how T-SQL works. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to executed a stored procedure over a linked server and return some logging information. In the procedure I set the default values to 0 like in the example above. Only when the procedure executes correctly does it update the values, and return correct results, but when the procedures encounters an error the value isn't changed from 0 and returns `NULL`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you might have answered my question. The OUTPUT flag doesn't make it strictly an outgoing variable, but is also passed in. I think this is what was confusing for me. Since if it isn't updated by the procedure it remains `NULL` if it was `NULL` when it was initialized.

Comment: Correct, there are no output *only* parameters, @TeunKruijer, just Input [only] and Input/Output parameters. If you assign a default value to an `OUTPUT` parameter then if you ever want to get the output value of that parameter you *have* to also treat it as an input parameter, overriding the default value. For `OUTPUT` parameters, the default value is better seen as a way to make the parameter optional, unless you truly want to treat is as both an input/output value.